# TFS WorkItem Layout problem

Tags: layout, tfs, customization, tfs-workitem

I'm customizing a TFS Work Item Type, adding a 'Business Description' HTML Field, but I cannot get the Layout right:

```
      <Tab Label="Details">
        <Group>
          <Column PercentWidth="60">
            <Control FieldName="Customer.BusinessDescription" Type="HtmlFieldControl" Label="Business Description:" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" />
          </Column>
          <Column PercentWidth="40">
            <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Symptom" Type="HtmlFieldControl" Label="Symptom:" LabelPosition="Top" />
            <Control FieldName="System.History" Type="WorkItemLogControl" Label="&amp;History:" LabelPosition="Top" />
          </Column>
        </Group>
      </Tab>
```

This turns out like this:
[image: undesired layout]

While I really want this ('Photoshopped' with MSPaint):
[image: desired layout]

I have played around with the Fill properties on all three fields, have already set the MinimumSize property on the BusinessDescription field, added a group inside the left column, but I do not seem to find a solution for this.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to create a group inside both the left and right columns:

```
<Tab Label="Details">
  <Group>
    <Column PercentWidth="60">
      <Group>
        <Column PercentWidth="100">
          <Control FieldName="Customer.BusinessDescription" Type="HtmlFieldControl" Label="Business Description:" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" />
        </Column>
      </Group>
    </Column>
    <Column PercentWidth="40">
      <Group>
        <Column PercentWidth="100">
          <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Symptom" Type="HtmlFieldControl" Label="Symptom:" LabelPosition="Top" />
          <Control FieldName="System.History" Type="WorkItemLogControl" Label="&amp;History:" LabelPosition="Top" />
        </Column>
      </Group>
    </Column>
  </Group>
</Tab>
```

You may also want to check out the Process Editor Power Tool - this provides a GUI interface to editing work item types.

Comment: Thanks, another group in the right column... did not think of that.

Comment: And yes I do use the Power Tools, but figured the xml is more clear to show the actual content. Funny thing is the Power Tools preview does not show the correct layout, neither does TFS Web Access. VS and MTM do ;-|

Comment: Oh, bother.  One thing to note is that the different clients can have different layouts, so if you can tweak the web layout into something a bit more preferable, you can deploy a web-only layout without changing the Visual Studio layout.  You can do `<Layout Target="$device">` where $device is WinForms for Visual Studio and MTM, Web for Web Access and SWT for Team Explorer Everywhere.

Comment: @edward-thomsom Who, super! Did not know about the Layout Target="$device">` option. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194952.aspx#SpecifyingLayouts]`<

Comment: See also [this post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/665743/workitem-layout-is-not-the-same-across-vs-and-tfs-web-access) about bad layouts in Web Access.